# Delete row in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Here is my code, when i click on the "+" button, the row increments-That's fine.
At the same time, I want that when I click on the "X" button, the row gets deleted. I am so badly stuck on this. 
Can anyone help me on this

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
def __init__(self,master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    #self.master=master
    self.init_window()

def init_window(self):
    self.master.title("Delete Row")
    self.frameOne=Frame(self.master)
    self.frameOne.grid(row=0,column=0)

    self.frameTwo=Frame(self.master)
    self.frameTwo.grid(row=1,column=0)
    #The purpose of creating a "frameTwo" is to add scrollbar
    self.canvas=Canvas(self.frameTwo)
    self.listFrame=Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scrollb=Scrollbar(self.master,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.scrollb.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew")
    self.canvas["yscrollcommand"]=self.scrollb.set


    self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.listFrame,anchor="nw")
    self.listFrame.bind("<Configure>",self.AuxscrollFunction)
    self.scrollb.grid_forget()

    self.canvas.pack(side="left")
    self.frameThree=Frame(self.master)
    self.frameThree.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.welcome=Button(self.frameOne,text="Welcome",command=self.welcome_to,width=10)
    self.welcome.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)        
def AuxscrollFunction(self,event):

    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"),width=1300,height=750)
def welcome_to(self):
    try:
        self.main()
        self.scrollb.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew")
    except ValueError:
        showerror("Not working")
def main(self):
    self.welcome.grid_remove()
    menu=Menu(self.listFrame)
    self.master.config(menu=menu)
    #creating the menu bar object-File
    file=Menu(menu)
    #adding commands to File 
    file.add_command(label="New")
    file.add_command(label="Load")
    file.add_command(label="Save")
    file.add_command(label="Save As")
    file.add_command(label="Exit",command=self.client_exit)
    #adding File to the Menu bar
    menu.add_cascade(label="File",menu=file)
    # Name and Description
    self.entry=Entry(self.listFrame)
    self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky="EW")
    nameLabel=Label(self.listFrame,text="NAME")
    nameLabel.grid(column=0,row=0)
    self.entry=Entry(self.listFrame)
    self.entry.grid(column=1,row=1,columnspan=8,sticky="EW")
    descriptionLabel=Label(self.listFrame,text="DESCRIPTION")
    descriptionLabel.grid(column=0,row=1)

    Box=Button(self.listFrame,text="Box",bg="white")
    Box.grid(column=0,row=2)
    Button1=Button(self.listFrame,text="+",command=self.combo,fg="green")
    Button1.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky="W")
    self.num=10



def client_exit(self):
    exit()

def tryon(self):
    BurstCountButton=Button(self.listFrame,text="Button 1")
    BurstCountButton.grid(column=2,row=2)
    DelayLabel=Label(self.listFrame,text="Label 1")
    DelayLabel.grid(column=4,row=2)

    tryLabel=Label(self.listFrame,text="Label 2")
    tryLabel.grid(column=1,row=int(self.num),sticky="EW")
    self.entry=Entry(self.listFrame)
    self.entry.grid(column=2,row=int(self.num),sticky="EW")
    TimesLabel=Label(self.listFrame,text="Label 2")
    TimesLabel.grid(column=3,row=int(self.num))
    self.entry=Entry(self.listFrame)
    self.entry.grid(column=4,row=int(self.num),sticky="EW")
    var=StringVar()
    menu1=OptionMenu(self.listFrame,var,"")
    menu1.config(width=10)
    menu1.grid(column=5,row=int(self.num))
    var.set("")
    andLabel=Label(self.listFrame,text="and")
    andLabel.grid(column=6,row=int(self.num))
    self.entry=Entry(self.listFrame)
    self.entry.grid(column=7,row=int(self.num),sticky="EW")
    menu2=OptionMenu(self.listFrame,var,")")
    menu2.config(width=10)
    menu2.grid(column=8,row=int(self.num))
    var.set("")
    closeButton=Button(self.listFrame,text="X",fg="red")
    closeButton.grid(column=9,row=int(self.num))
    self.num=self.num+1
    self.b=self.num

def mbutton(self):
    global counter
    counter+=1
    label=Label(self.listFrame,text="tryon(%s)"%counter)
    label.config(text="tryon(%s)"%counter,fg="blue")
    label.grid(column=0,row=int(self.num))


def combo(self):
    self.mbutton()
    self.tryon()



 if __name__ == "__main__":
counter=0
count_service=0
root = Tk()

aplicacion = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How are you stuck? What problem are you having? I don't where the button is calling any function.

Comment: ` closeButton=Button(self.listFrame,text="X",fg="red")
    closeButton.grid(column=9,row=int(self.num))`
Yes, I am stuck. I want to make "X" button functional.  But i dont know how. "X" button should delete the row.

Comment: How are you stuck? Do you know how to call a function from a button? Do you know how to destroy a widget? What part of the problem do you need help with? What have you tried?

Comment: i know how to call a function(see the example, my "+" button works fine.It add a row when i clicked it). But i am not able to figure out that how my "-" button should function so that it can delete the respective row

Comment: You should try to use the method grid_slaves() on the parent widget self.listFrame in order to retrieve the label widgets, then use the method grid_forget () on the widget to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def DeleteSelection(self):
    self.num=self.num-1
    #print("in delete num is",self.num)
    l=list(self.listFrame.grid_slaves(row=int(self.num)))
    #print(l)
    for w in l:
        w.grid_forget()
```

Comment: Thanks guysThis was a huge help!!

Comment: Be careful - this only removes a row from view, it doesn't actually delete it.